# Не создается объект PDO

Tags: php, oracle, apache2

Доброго времени суток!
Я пытаюсь осуществить соединение с БД Oracle через PHP. Когда я пробую соединиться через  $dbh = new PDO($dsn, $user, $password) , то выводится ошибка:

> pdo_oci_handle_factory: ORA-12154: TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified (ext\pdo_oci\oci_driver.c:631)'

Однако, когда я соединяюсь через функцию oci_connect($user, $password, $shem) ,  соединение срабатывает. Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться из-за чего это может происходить?
P.S. на машине стоит  Apache2.2 и php 5.4.0

Comment: В документации на PDO в примере предлагается в самом php указать целиком блок из tnsnames. http://php.net/manual/ru/ref.pdo-oci.php попробуйте как там. Или укажите dbname равным имени раздела tnsnames и более ничего

Comment: попробовала и так и так, все равно не подключается(( в php php_pdo_oci.dll подключено, в логах ошибок нет, в PATH все прописано...

Comment: может значение dsn предоставите примерное а то люд гадает какая там у вас схема? какой драйвер?

Comment: dsn определяю таким образом:  $dsn='oci:dbname=base_name;charset=AL32UTF8'

Answer (score 1):

Что у вас находится в переменной $dsn ?

Например у меня, соединение с БД MySQL (хотя это не принципиально, какая СУБД) через прослойку PDO выглядит сл. образом:

```
class Db {
    public static function getConnection() {
        $host = 'localhost';
        $dbname = 'DataBase';
        $user = 'root';
        $password = 'Passwword';
        $charsetByDefault = array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES utf8');
        $db = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$dbname", $user, $password, $charsetByDefault);
        return $db;
    }
}
```

И все, разумеется, работает.

Comment: переменную $dsn конструирую таким  образом: $dsn ='oci:dbname=NameBase;host=IP_Server_With_DB;charset=AL32UTF8'   Разумеется, все данные беру из tnsnames.ora  Для  oci_connect($user, $password, $shem), переменная $shem='IP_Server_With_DB/NameBase'

Comment: Но объект PDO все равно не создается(

Comment: Вот как раз MySQL это или oracle очень даже принципиально. В oracle с коннектом все не как у других БД, так что ответ на основе MySQL не корректен. Многим средствам соединения требуются записи в tnsnames.ora.

Comment: запись в tnsname.ora есть, через TOAD я могу подключиться к базе, но вот через объект PDO не получается